# .htaccess – Remove directory and extension from URL

Tags: .htaccess

My URL looks like this, for example:

```
example.com/live/file1.php
```

So, I want users to access it like this:

```
example.com/file1
```

I’ve added this to the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!live/)(.*)$ live/$1 [L,NC]
```

... and this for the `live` folder:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I think it works, but I want the `.php` extension to be hidden from the URL when I access `example.com/file1.php`.

**Is this the right way to do it?**

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ live/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ live/$1




RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```